# Which AMQPSpout are you using?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, apache-storm

I would like to consume messages from the RabbitMQ using a an AMQP Spout.
Can you recommend me some good one (meaning tested also on the production)?

Answer (score 0):

I found this spout https://github.com/ppat/storm-rabbitmq suitable for my project. I didn't tested yet in production, but it behaves well in the development phase.
  I hope that this answer will help others.
Good luck.
  Florin

Comment: you would write the question and also an answer and appreciate yourself?